# Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Introduction**

I am working with the bootstrap framework.Working specifically with  "Bootstrap Tabs"(hide/show).My current bootstrap version is 3 and jquery version is 3.0.2 something.

**Problem**

My tabs are not working, unless i load jquery of version less than 1.6.But then ajax making problem with jquery less than 1.6. Chrome console give me this error.

> bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires
> jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

I tried different fallback techniques but couldn't implement correctly.

I am stuck here for 2 days, if someone have any idea or any reference, please do help.Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use `jquery.migrate.js` or use both the versions and declare `$.noConflict`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Currently Bootstrap 3.x does not support jQuery 3.x as reported here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834

The issue is caused by:

> jQuery 3 is more strict than jQuery 2. It's like XHTML and HTML.
>   Backward compatibility is preserved and code doesn't look like a mess.
>   If I'm not mistaken, all you need to do is replace show() and hide()
>   functions with .css('display', '') or addClass('hidden') and fix a
>   selector in alert.js (QUnit fails on this line because $('#') is
>   invalid in jQuery 3)

It is fixed in the Bootstrap 3.3.7 release: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834#issuecomment-225039913

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1 for help

Comment: @IrvinDominin After upgrading jquery to 3.2.1 and Bootstrap to `v4.0.0-alpha.6` in `VS2017` I'm still getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

Latest current version of Bootstrap (3.3.7) now supports jQuery 3+, as per developer's comment here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834.

Comment: If you are using VS make sure the minified version of Bootstrap is the new version.  The update does not create the new minified file.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Bower to manage your javascript packages, to exclude jquery 3.0 you should specify the version of jquery like:

```
"jquery": "^2.2"
```

in your `bower.json`.

The `bower.json` of `jquery-ui` package has a following line:

```
"jquery": ">=1.6"
```

Because of it Bower installs the latest version of jQuery, which causes your problem.

Note that jQuery 3.0 is released as of June 9, 2016.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes i resolved the problem, +1 for help

Answer (score 4):

**Put This Code In Functions.php**

```
wp_deregister_script(‘jquery’);
wp_register_script(‘jquery’, ‘//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js’, false, null);
wp_enqueue_script(‘jquery’);
```

Here is Reference URL:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-bootstraps-javascript-requires-at-least-jquery-v1-9-1/

Answer (score 3):

What solved my problem is actually loading jquery lower version before bootstrap.js and then loading jquery higher version after bootstrap.js to resolve conflicts.Above is my example

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/App_Theme/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: This loads jQuery two times.

Answer (score 2):

As for me, everything  simple. It's all  about queue links files. I need to move links like this:

```
<head>
     <script src="js/jquery1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.js"> </script>       
</head>
```

After all - it's working prorerly.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and I have not jquery 1.8.2 in my web pages.I solve my problem by change version of jquery in **packages.config**

change

```
  <package id="AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="jQuery" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

to

```
<package id="AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net45" />
```

my jquery version is **2.1.4**

Answer (score 2):

So I had the new version of Bootstrap but for some reason the min version was still the old version which did not support the JQuery 3.  I removed the minified bootstrap JS then reminified the new Bootstrap.js and deployed and the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

---

With a migration to wordpress 5.6, i had the same problem : a conflict between bootstrap and jquery.
Navigation on my websites didn't work for all dropdown menus.
I have changed boostrap3.3.6 to boostrap3.3.7 in my folder css + js to get a bootstrap working with jquery 1.9.1 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran across this error in WordPress 5.6 where accordions stopped working.  Upgrading the JS and CSS from boostrap3.3.6 to boostrap3.3.7 fixed the error for me too.