# Bootstrap Collapsible Menu not working when clicking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My collapsible menu in Bootstrap doesn't appear to be working - 
can anyone help me what is the problem? Right now it displays the 
Collapsible Menu , but clicking it does nothing in visual 
studio 2015,but it work in w3school example,here:
[w3school collapsible menu example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible&stacked=h)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
        <div id="demo" class="collapse">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use their example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936751/bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery-version-1-9-1-or-higher-but-lower-than-v)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do refer the code and its working fine according to your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
        <div id="demo" class="collapse">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```