# Using Newer version jquery breaks bootstrap dropdowns

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

There I am building a shopping website and I came upon the issue of a newer version of jquery breaking my bootstrap navbar drop downs. I have tried updating the bootstrap as well and using the bundle config as well but neither of these work. The reason I need the new version is that I am using brain tree which works well with the latest version of bootstrap but not with version 1.10.2 of jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/funky.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">

        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="@Url.Action("Home", "ProductInfo")">
            <img style="max-width:40px; margin-top: -7px;"
                 src="~/img/1.jpg"></a>
</div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sports <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("List", "ProductInfo")">Sports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu navbar-left">
                  <li><a href="#">@Html.Action("Menu", "Navagation")</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu navbar-left">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>

      <form class="navbar-form nav navbar-nav" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


            <li>
                     @Html.Action("CartNavSummary", "Cart")
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>My Acc <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>



        <div> @*class="container body-content"*@
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script> <--------- doesnt work
        @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>*@ <--------works
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No its not supported. [bower.json](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/bower.json)

Comment: vanburen do you know away around this as I am sure you have probably already encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Yes it's possible: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page and you can review [jQuery.noConflic()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) in the Docs.

Comment: Hi, Currently Bootstrap 3.x does not support jQuery 3.x. Please check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936751/bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery-version-1-9-1-or-higher-but-lower-than-v