# Bootstrap Button Collapse in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

While following "Bootstrap 3 Tutorials - #2 - Responsive Collapsing Navbar [1080p]", I got stuck w/ this button; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpWlaOeGZ_4

When button is cliked, home link is supposed to show in mobile size of the page.
But nothing happens, can anyone help me with this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">My Home</a>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">Button Test</button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>                
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936751/bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery-version-1-9-1-or-higher-but-lower-than-v)

Comment: You need to use a newer version of jQuery. The jQuery version will depend on which version of Bootstrap you are using. **_jquery 1.9.1 - 2 for Bootstrap v3.3.6 & below_** or **_jquery 1.9.1 - 3 for v3.3.7_** See [bower.json](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/bower.json) for the newest Bootstrap release.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  @vanburen. It works fine as you commented