# bootsrap nav-bar collapsable cannot make it work

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i'm developing an Angularjs application and i'd like to make it multiplatform so to do that i'm trying to use Bootsrap, i found a template i'd like to follow (https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-business-frontpage/#) the problem is that i want to transform the navbar when the screen size is smaller.

[image]

[image]

but i don't know what i'm missing, because it does correctly the transformation to a button but then, the button is not clickable so the options 'inicio', 'servicios' and 'contacto' are unreachable.

Any help would be awesome, here you have the css and html files:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="home">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>HOME</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-resource.js"></script>   

        <link href="/web/resources/css/business-frontpage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="/web/resources/js/home/home-service.js"></script>
        <script src="/web/resources/js/home/home-controller.js"></script>
        <script src="/web/resources/js/home/home-app.js"></script>
        <script src="/web/resources/lib/translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
        <script src="/web/resources/js/generic/urlLanguageStorage.js"></script>
        <script src="/web/resources/lib/translate/angular-translate-loader-url.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

               <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a ui-sref="home" translate>navegacion.inicio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a ui-sref="servicios" translate>navegacion.servicios</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a ui-sref="contacto" translate>navegacion.contacto</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Image Background Page Header -->
    <!-- Note: The background image is set within the business-casual.css file. -->
    <header class="business-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1><a class="tagline" ui-sref="home" translate>titulo.alergenos</a></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>


<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div> 
</div>



<div class="container">
<!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </footer>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/*
 * Start Bootstrap - Business Frontpage (http://startbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2013-2016 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE)
 */

body {
    padding-top: 50px; /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}

/* Header Image Background - Change the URL below to your image path (example: ../images/background.jpg) */

.business-header {
    height: 400px;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/1920x400') center center no-repeat scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

/* Customize the text color and shadow color and to optimize text legibility. */

.tagline {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.img-center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

EDIT
I created a Jsfidlle https://jsfiddle.net/txominsirera/v8ups1hc/

Comment: Could  you create [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [plunker](https://plnkr.co)?

Comment: @txomin Where is your `bootstrap.js` included?

Comment: you were right @Arif i missed the bootstrap.js file, but it didnt work anyways. I created a jjsfiddle if it helps...

Comment: You need to use a lower version of jquery because of the Bootstrap version you are using. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936751/bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery-version-1-9-1-or-higher-but-lower-than-v

Comment: In your jsfiddle your versions are right but bootstrapjs comes after jquery.

Comment: you mean i only need to change the order i import the libraries? @vanburen

Comment: Yes, bootstrapjs needs to be placed after jQuery and the right versions as well.

Comment: Thanks @vanburen, you can put your comment as an answer if you want and i'll mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Both *`jQuery`* and *`Bootstrap.js`* should be included with *`jQuery`* placed *before* *`Bootstrap.js`*.

### Note: The version of *`jQuery`* that *can* be used will vary depending on the version of *`Bootstrap`* being used (or vice versa).

---

### Bootstrap [Version 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

> JS Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.
>   Specifically, they require [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/), and our own JavaScript
>   plugins. Place the following `<script>`s near the end of your pages,
>   right before the closing `</body`> tag, to enable them. jQuery must come
>   first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.
>
> We use [jQuery’s slim build](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/), but the full version is also supported.

---

#### For Release [***v4.0.0-beta.2 package.json***](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0-beta.2/package.json)

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.7"
},
```

---

### Bootstrap [Version 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)

> **jQuery required**
>
> Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery
>   to be included, as shown in the [starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template). [Consult our
>   bower.json](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/bower.json) to see which versions of jQuery are supported.

#### For Release [v3.3.7 Changelog](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v3.3.7) & [***bower.json***](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/bower.json)

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3"
}
```

---

#### For [v3.3.6 *bower.json*](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/bower.json)

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": ">= 1.9.1 - 2"
}
```

---

#### For v3.3.0 - [v3.3.5 *bower.json*](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.5/bower.json)

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": ">= 1.9.1"
}
```

*This does not account for the release of jQuery v3.0*

---

#### For v3.0.0rc1 - [v3.2.0 *bower.json*](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.2.0/bower.json)

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": ">= 1.9.0"
}
```

*This does not account for the release of jQuery v3.0*