# bootstrap 3 navbar collapse button not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

[this is the image with probelem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3udnK.png)
I am a student and I am in a problem with bootstrap. I having a problem to create a collapse in bootstrap I will try everything but it still not working please help.

here is my codes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Anything</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <style>
  body {
  padding-top: 51px;
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0px;
 font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
}
 </style>
 
 <body>
  
  <!-- NavBar -->
   
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   
   <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Anything</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
     <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">COURCES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">THEMES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">EXTRA</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
   </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootsrap nav-bar collapsable cannot make it work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705798/bootsrap-nav-bar-collapsable-cannot-make-it-work)

Answer (score 4):

You need to load the JQuery library before Bootstrap because JQuery is a dependency for the Bootstrap javascript file. To fix just swap these two lines of code around:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

As an aside: All Bootstrap Javascript plugins need JQuery. The [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) css feature makes use of the [collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) Javascript plugin in Bootstrap and therefore requires JQuery.