# Bootstrap - The links do not appear on the button when the compact page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

The links do not appear on the button when the compact page. 
The button is dead, does not respond.

This is my code:

```
 <div id="geral" class="container">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!--Navbar header-->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <!--Button-->
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1" aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-controls="navbar">
                   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
                        <!--Nome do projeto-->
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>

                    </div>
                    <!--navbar collapse-->
                    <div id="navbar1" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link2</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link3</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </nav>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine (you do have a missing closing `</div>` btw). Have you checked your console for errors because this is generally due to not having jQuery and/or BootstrapJS or having them in the wrong order. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705798/bootsrap-nav-bar-collapsable-cannot-make-it-work/38709086#38709086

Comment: Thank you ! I forgot the JQuery file.

Comment: No problem and you're welcome.