# Bootstrap collapsed navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have written a simple collapsible navbar on my site with bootstrap but don't understand why on the live version once collapsed it isn't working. If I copy/paste the code on, for example, w3school try it site the code works. Don't understand what's wrong with it, any help?

[Live version](http://www.fantamondi.it/cotli/index.php)

Link to w3school try it editor with a similar toolbar
[w3school try it](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h)

and here's the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button data-target="#cotliNavbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button>
        <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">Crusaders of the Lost Idols fansite</a>
    </div>
    <div id="cotliNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="missions">Missions</a></li>
        <li><a href="crusaders">Crusaders</a></li>
        <li><a href="recommendation">Recommendation</a></li>
        <li><a href="hints">Hints</a></li>
    </ul><ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="user"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> taised</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
    </ul>     </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

using bootstrap 3.3.7 and jquery 1.9.0

Edit: the linked question is regarding the order of jquery and bootstrap, which is not the case, in my case it was a missing js and a wrong jquery version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootsrap nav-bar collapsable cannot make it work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705798/bootsrap-nav-bar-collapsable-cannot-make-it-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your code where you are including the bootstrap.js file.  You will need to include that file after jquery to allow for the collapsing to work correctly:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

For more info on getting started with bootstrap check out their documentation: 
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: That's and not only, but bootstrap requires a jquery min version of 1.9.1 while i'm using 1.9.0. Thanks